# Customization of radio button with image in extjs

Tags: css, extjs

I have tried a lot of possibilities to provide customize CSS in Ext widget with image, not yet succeeded, already checked on internet but can not able to use them, I know CSS for customizing image with radio, but in case of extjs the widget `<div>` is totally different, I can not put image inside the widget, however I can manage to design the radio button,but unable to put css for the corresponding checked radio button image.

```
<?php foreach ($themelist as $list){ ?>
        <div  class= "theme-wrapper">
        <label class="theme-image <?php echo $list['id'] == 'gray' ? 'checked-image' : '' ;?>">
        <div widget="radio" class="theme-radio"  name="theme" boxLabel="<?php echo $list['name']; ?>" inputValue="<?php echo $list['id']; ?>" 
    checked = <?= $list['id'] == 'gray' ? 'true' : '' ; ?>></div>
        <img src="../resources/app/images/capture.png" alt="" />
    </label>
    <div class="theme-name"><?php echo $list['name'];?></div>
</div><?php } ?>
```

is there any way  in CSS to change image style outside the radio button section. Hence it is Ext js 3.4, not much help found over internet. Help me if any one have any idea about it. Thank you.

```
<div class="theme-radio" id="ext-gen314">
 <div class="x-form-check-wrap" id="ext-gen316">
  <div class="x-form-radio-inner x-form-check-checked" id="ext-gen315"><input type="radio" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1155" name="theme" class=" x-form-radio x-form-field" value="gray" checked=""></div><label class="x-form-cb-label" for="ext-comp-1155" id="ext-gen317">Grey (Default)</label></div></div>
```

here is the fiddle code [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6r8rozu0/7/)

Comment: It would be helpful for us if you share your code in some fiddle.We can fix it over there directly.

Comment: @Tejas1991 I have updated the fiddle code, please help me if there is any way.

Comment: What version of ExtJS do you use?

Comment: @sergeynovikov version 3.4

Answer (score 0):

Try do as there

```
<label class="check">
    <input type="radio">
    <span>Value</span>
</label>

.check {
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.check input {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale(0);
}

.check span:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background:#000;
}

.check input:checked + span:before {
    background: red;
}
```

JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/grinmax_/7fpbkz9s/1/

Comment: I have already tried this one but not succeeded, I edited the question with fiddle plz check the fiddle.

Comment: @RajeshDey we can change html structure?

Comment: No, we can't , thats the problem, should maintain the structure, the whole structure made in extjs :(